# Have a problem with error: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel

Have a problem with error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

I put in route post method and in form to but idk why it still show errors...

```
//route
Route::post('posts/{post}/comment', 'CommentController@store'); 

//controller
class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, $post_id)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'content' => 'required',
        ]);
        //$post = Post::find($post_id);
        $comment = new Comment;
        $comment->content = $request->input('content');
        $comment->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        //$comment->post()->associate($post);
        $comment->save();

        return redirect('/posts')->with('success','Post Created');
    }
}

//form
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'POST','action' => ['CommentController@store', $post->id]]) }}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        {{ Form::label('comment', "Comment:") }}
        {{ Form::textarea('content', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Add Comment', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) }}
    </div>
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

//web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');

Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');

Route::get('/services', 'PagesController@services');

Route::resource('posts','PostsController');

Route::post('/posts/{post}/comment', 'CommentController@store');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I want when I press button for adding a new comment in Posts/show view to send me where need to send and it only gives me an error.

Comment: first add @csrf to your form and see what will happen next

Comment: Hey, I think your validation fails( usually redirects to same page, but with GET request). Could you try removing the validation to test?

Comment: If you're not filling out the `<textarea>`, your validation will fail and the request will be redirected to the `GET` version of `posts/{post}/comment`. I personally don't use `$this->validate()` in my controllers, so I'm not sure to handle this, but that's what's happening.

Comment: i add @csrf and i remove validation now and still same problem..

Comment: What @TimLewis sais. I usually rather use the Validator Facade. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators is the resource on how to use it.

Comment: Do you have a redirect set up anywhere else? Watch the Network requests in the Developer console to see where it's traversing and which route is throwing the error.

Comment: Are you sure the route which fails is `posts/{post}/comment` and not `/posts` ?

Comment: Ohh, another thing, can you show us the complete route file(web.php)? Often this can be caused by competing routes which look alike

Comment: idk why dont wotk ctrl+k now in comments, i try all and again dont work somewhere i make mistake and idk where

Comment: i put web.php now

Comment: Did you try running `php artisan route:list` first to check where your post method is pointing at? If all else fails I'd try to first make it work with a 'regular' form.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$post` in `public function store(Request $request, $post_id)` ??

Answer (score 0):

Please change as below. please make sure whenever you use `resource` in route, it should always below of other related route.when call to route, it will call `posts/{$id}/edit` it is `get` method. for more info please check below blog.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers

```
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comment', 'CommentController@store');
```

to

```
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comment', 'CommentController@store');
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
```